# Define custom time format

Tags: go, posix, datetime-format

I am trying to write a custom date format string as required by my application. 
Using the Go time package I get the format using a clumsy function (see below).

Also since this function will be called millions of times every day, I want this to be super efficient too. Is there a POSIX style formatting available in Go?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Printf("Time now is %d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d",
        t.Year(), t.Month(), t.Day(), t.Hour(), t.Minute(), t.Second())
}
```

Comment: you can use `Unix()` method of time package to get unix timstamp. Which date format do you want ? Mention in the post

Comment: @Ram use the `Format` method https://play.golang.org/p/JlUyGVK0aPR

Comment: @Ram another solution, less elegant but presumably faster when compared to the `Format` method, would be to use `strconv` package's `Itoa` function and manual handling of the two-digit padding.

Comment: ... e.g. something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/TZh1U9NxtbA

Comment: I don't get why this got downvoted to be honest, seems a legitimate question, formatting time in Go is not as straightforward as in other languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go there are built in layouts to pass to the `.Format()` method of `Time` ([see `func (Time) Format`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format)), one of these could be what you are looking for:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.ANSIC))
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.UnixDate))
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
}
```

This is going to be faster than `fmt.Printf("...", t.Year(), t.Month(), ...)`, but we're talking about microseconds "faster" here, so there really is no big difference.

Output:

```
Sun Jun 10 13:18:09 2018
Sun Jun 10 13:18:09 UTC 2018
2018-06-10T13:18:09Z
```

There are a lot more predefined layouts, so you can check all of them out and see if one of them fits your needs. Here they are directly from the source code:

```
const (
    ANSIC       = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"
    UnixDate    = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006"
    RubyDate    = "Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006"
    RFC822      = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"
    RFC822Z     = "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700" // RFC822 with numeric zone
    RFC850      = "Monday, 02-Jan-06 15:04:05 MST"
    RFC1123     = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
    RFC1123Z    = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700" // RFC1123 with numeric zone
    RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
    RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
    Kitchen     = "3:04PM"
    // Handy time stamps.
    Stamp      = "Jan _2 15:04:05"
    StampMilli = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000"
    StampMicro = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000"
    StampNano  = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000000"
)
```

Other than that, **it's just a matter of creating your own layout**, there really is no difference.

---

To create a custom layout string, quoting from the documentation:

> The layout string used by the `Parse` function and `Format` method shows by example how the reference time should be represented. We stress that **one must show how the reference time is formatted, not a time of the user's choosing**. Thus each layout string is a representation of the time stamp: `Jan 2 15:04:05 2006 MST`.

So, for example:

```
fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("Mon January 2, 2006 - 15:04:05.000"))
```

gives:

```
Sun June 10, 2018 - 17:49:32.557
```

**If you want something different you'll just have to format the date `Jan 2 15:04:05 2006 MST` how you would want it to be displayed.** You can also take a look at [the relative page](https://gobyexample.com/time-formatting-parsing) on Go by Example.

Comment: this is what I need. How do I create my own format string. Are there examples of that

Comment: @Ram added to the answer.

Comment: I just benchmarked all methods 1) using fmt.printf(... t.year()) 2) using itoa 3) using format. Seems all are almost same

Just curious why would be the reference date be so chosen

Comment: @Ram No particular reason for the reference date. From the doc: "an easy way to remember this value is that it holds, when presented in this order, the values 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, -7". I guess that may be a reason.